# JavaScript 'new' weird usage

Tags: javascript

If a constructor function is just a function that with 'new' returns object why instead of usual:

```
function One(message){
    this.message = message;
}

One.prototype.getMessage = function() {
    console.log(this.message);
}
```

we do not do:

```
function Two(message){
    return {
        message: message,
        getMessage: function() {
            console.log(this.message);
        }
    }
}
```

The usage is the same and result (in this simple case) the same:

```
var o1 = new One('One');
o1.getMessage();

var o2 = new Two('Two');
o2.getMessage();
```

I got two answers:

1. 'prototype' of o2 is Object so, `o2 instanceof Two` returns false
2. function getMessage is defined for each instance of Two separately but One is defined only in One's prototype.

Any other answers "why it's wrong"?

Comment: `Two` isn't a normal constructor function, as it returns an object. JS just uses the object that's returned rather than the created object.

Comment: Nothing is wrong here. It is a matter of taste. The second variant seems simplier, and a scripting engine should optimize the memory consumption on that as well.

Comment: @AndersLindén Are you sure about the memory consumption part? I'm not sure that can be optimized without potentially modifying the function's scope which could cause undesired consequences. I'm not sure the scripting engine would risk this.

Comment: Also, the second function could be written shorter: function Two(message){ return { getMessage: function(){console.log(message);}}}

Comment: No, I am not sure about the memory consumption part, but it seems like getMessage can be assigned one and the same function object every time you run Two.

Comment: Well, it will still point to a function object, so no, but who cares :)

Comment: I think the benefit of writing it simplier is worth something and a scripting engine that was good enough would make the same result of the examples, maybe we dont have such a scripting engine in existence yet, dunno

Answer (score 3):

Option1 associates the method with the type, so that you don't have to redefine the function every time you need a `One` type. This results in better performance and less memory usage.

In option 2 you are redefining a dynamic object every time you instantiate the object.

Comment: @Yoorek In support of this answer, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/mFu7D/1/) fiddle. Open you console by pressing `F12` and look at the objects returned. You'll notice that `One` does not have the function `getMessage` as a property of the `One` object. Instead it is defined in the `__proto__` object of `One`. `Two` however has `getMessage` defined as an object property of `Two` rather than a property of the `__proto__` object.

Comment: @War10ck - that is exactly what my answer no. 2 stated already

Comment: @TGH Not sure if it is just general description of what I stated in answer 2.

Answer (score 0):

What I know is that when you add property to prototype you are ensuring that this property is shared between all instances,  thus it is memory optimization if you will have one object instantiated hundred times.

If you come from typical OOP like c#, then adding a property to a prototype is similar to some extent to defining a static field

`Public static string msg = " hello";`

Answer (score 0):

Do `100x new Two(message)` and you will create `100x getMessage function`. So thats quite a memory impact if the get message become quite complicated.
If you write it in to prototype, you will get only one function no metters how many times you will create a new instance of Two. Accessing a prototype is a little bit slower than direct accessing.
If its singleton, you don't need prototype.
If its factory, please go with prototype.

FYI: Im using es6, so prototype everywhere :)

Comment: your question is "why is this wrong" There is nothing wrong on this  approach as I mention. Thats what I tried to explain here. Sometimes you need to have scoped function for example when you mimic class in es5.